# Sorting NSMutableArray Removing First Element

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How to sort an NSMutableArray numerically when it contains objects like follows:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"P3",@"P1",@"P4",@"P10", nil];
```

The output of the same should be like: P1, P3, P4, P10

Comment: First Latter always having one character?

Comment: Yes, It will always have one character.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you show some code?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: It is always 'P' ?

Comment: Yes prefix start with always "P".

Comment: oka then it's so easy

Comment: So why don't you try something instead of just asking others to write code for you?

Comment: Hey @BhargavSoni would you accept and mark an answer if it works for you? It might help some other fellow developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSNumericSearch`

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString*  _Nonnull str1, NSString*  _Nonnull str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

From the Header Documentation-

> NSNumericSearch = 64,     /* Added in 10.2; Numbers within strings are compared using numeric value, that is, Foo2.txt < Foo7.txt < Foo25.txt; only applies to compare methods, not find */

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer?

Comment: It just doesn't work out in general. Misleading for other developers. Hope that's not an offensive.

Comment: "in general"?  It was coded for this specific issue and does work as far as I  know.  It's not at all "wrong" or misleading.

Comment: Sorry Sir. I just thought that we are not in a competition and we should provide recommended approaches by SDK!

Comment: Well I actually like your answer better as it's cleaner, however I would imagine mine is quicker.  Both are right as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is always a character at the start of the strings, then:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger i1 = [[obj1 substringFromIndex:1] integerValue];
    NSInteger i2 = [[obj2 substringFromIndex:1] integerValue];
    if (i1 > i2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (i1 < i2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"P3",@"P1",@"P4",@"P10", nil];

NSLog(@"Array: %@",array);
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

NSArray *sorters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lastNameDescriptor, nil];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];

NSMutableArray *sortArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[sortArray addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];

NSLog(@"sortArray : %@",sortArray);
```

Output::

```
2016-06-15 16:47:47.707 test[5283:150858] Array: (
P3,
P1,
P4,
P10
)
2016-06-15 16:47:47.708 test[5283:150858] sortArray : (
P1,
P3,
P4,
P10
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also sort `NSArray`or `NSMutableArray` using `NSSortDescriptor`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [<arrayToBeSorted> sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
NSLog(@"Result = %@", sortedArray);
```